# mysql: what does 'r' mean?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been going through some code and repeatedly see the letter 'r' in queries, and I've never seen it before. I'm no mysql guru and cannot find references on the web that really make sense in this case.

Sample query:

```
SELECT * FROM database.table r
WHERE column = 'whatever'
AND otherColumn = 'whenever'
ORDER BY id, name
```

Comment: it looks like its just an alias for `database.table`, which could also be done with as such" `database.table AS r`.  This would usually require that you put `r.column` or `r.id`, but thats not the case in this example so im not sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That actually means that the table is being aliased from its long form to the letter/symbol 'r'.

It's a [red herring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring) in your case because 'r' is not used anywhere in the query and it doesn't need to be. Your query is not a good example of using aliases because there is only one table involved. If you join multiple tables then aliasing becomes handy (although not required) to specify which table's column you're referencing in your various query's clauses.

You can simply remove the 'r' and run your query.

```
SELECT * FROM database.table r
WHERE column = 'whatever'
AND otherColumn = 'whenever'
ORDER BY id, name
```

Or use it outright like: (though it's redundant here)

```
SELECT * FROM database.table r
WHERE r.column = 'whatever'
AND r.otherColumn = 'whenever'
ORDER BY r.id, r.name
```

BTW, SQL code like this is the reason I tend to use the keyword AS to highlight the fact that I am aliasing. So the FROM clause would look like this: `FROM database.table AS r`

As far as what that unused alias is doing there is a good question. My guess it that it's been getting cut, copied and pasted from some old query which used the alias but no one ever bother to remove it when it became unnecessary.

Comment: As perfect explanation as I can imagine. Thanks Paul.

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks for the kind feedback and check mark! Did I make you a fan of the AS keyword?

Comment: Absolutely! I probably would have known what it meant if the AS keyword were there (why the table isn't prefixed is still a mystery to me however). The query comes out of some PHP scripts, so it would make sense if there were other tables involved, but I don't see any signs of that so you're probably correct in guessing it's a copy/paste situation.

Answer (score 6):

It's an alias. It means: We **must** use `r` now instead of `database.table`.

We **can** use `r.column` but we are still allowed to use just `column` if there is no ambiguity.

```
SELECT * FROM database.table r
WHERE r.column = 'whatever'         --using the alias r
AND otherColumn = 'whenever'        --not using it
ORDER BY id, r.name                 --mixing
```

Comment: Not only "can" you use `r`, you "must" only use `r`. The original reference aliased as `r` is no longer available.

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi: Well I'll be darned! You're right. Never knew that one.

Answer (score 4):

`r` is an alias you can give to a table. You can reference table columns later by that alias, for example `r.column1`

Answer (score 4):

It's a table alias. If you're joining two tables with duplicated column names, you would disambiguate the query by saying some_table.id, the table alias allows you to just type r.id.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a table alias to me with the `AS` keyword omitted. In the sample query, the alias is unnecessary since only one table is being referenced and the alias is never used.

The relevant syntax for a table_reference is specified in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html) as `tbl_name [[AS] alias] [index_hint_list]`.